# 'pip install' two modules with the same namespace package

Tags: python, pip

I've created two wheels containing respectively foo/comp1.py and foo/comp2.py. 'foo' is a namespace package ([PEP420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)). When installing these two packages in the same folder I would expect pip to merge them. But it fails. Is it expected? Why?

Example:

```
pip_namespace>unzip -l comp1/dist/foo.comp1-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Archive:  comp1/dist/foo.comp1-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2016-01-27 14:45   foo/comp1.py
       31  2016-01-27 14:55   foo.comp1-1.0.0.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
      377  2016-01-27 14:55   foo.comp1-1.0.0.dist-info/metadata.json
        4  2016-01-27 14:55   foo.comp1-1.0.0.dist-info/top_level.txt
       92  2016-01-27 14:55   foo.comp1-1.0.0.dist-info/WHEEL
      244  2016-01-27 14:55   foo.comp1-1.0.0.dist-info/METADATA
      568  2016-01-27 14:55   foo.comp1-1.0.0.dist-info/RECORD
---------                     -------
     1316                     7 files

pip_namespace>unzip -l comp2/dist/foo.comp2-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Archive:  comp2/dist/foo.comp2-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2016-01-27 14:56   foo/comp2.py
       31  2016-01-27 14:57   foo.comp2-1.0.0.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
      377  2016-01-27 14:57   foo.comp2-1.0.0.dist-info/metadata.json
        4  2016-01-27 14:57   foo.comp2-1.0.0.dist-info/top_level.txt
       92  2016-01-27 14:57   foo.comp2-1.0.0.dist-info/WHEEL
      244  2016-01-27 14:57   foo.comp2-1.0.0.dist-info/METADATA
      568  2016-01-27 14:57   foo.comp2-1.0.0.dist-info/RECORD
---------                     -------
     1316                     7 files

pip_namespace>pip install -t test_pip comp1/dist/foo.comp1-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./comp1/dist/foo.comp1-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: foo.comp1
Successfully installed foo.comp1
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

pip_namespace>pip install -t test_pip comp2/dist/foo.comp2-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./comp2/dist/foo.comp2-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: foo.comp2
Successfully installed foo.comp2
Target directory /remote/devsup/users/flemaitre/tmp/pip_namespace/test_pip/foo already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

As a result comp2 is missing:

```
pip_namespace>find test_pip/foo
test_pip/foo
test_pip/foo/__pycache__
test_pip/foo/__pycache__/comp1.cpython-35.pyc
test_pip/foo/comp1.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38919020/4802862

Using this answer, I was able to deploy two wheels in the same top level namespace